# bootstrap parallax smooth scrolling issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, scroll

I have created a page with bootstrap js framework but page scroll is very slow when we use to scroll down also scroll up.

i was unable to find any solution if any body could tell me what can i do to scroll this page smooth and very effective

here is code snipped

```
<body>
    <div id="custom-navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="imgs/logo.png">
            </div>
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="custom-navbar-ul">
                    <li class="hoverY"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li class="hoverY"><a href="#">BENEFITS</a></li>
                    <li class="hoverY"><a href="#">APPSBRITE<br>
                        WIDGET</a></li>
                    <li class="hoverY"><a href="#">PLACEMENT<br>
                        GUIDE</a></li>
                    <li class="hoverY"><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
                    <li class="hoverY"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li class="hoverN">
                        <button type="button" id="sign-up" class="btn btn-sm">
                            <a href="#">SIGN UP</a></button></li>
                    <li class="hoverN">
                        <button type="button" id="sign-in" class="btn btn-sm">
                            <a href="#">SIGN IN</a></button></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="home-1" class="section" data-index="1" style="position: absolute; top: 0%;">
        </div>
        <div id="home-2" class="section" data-index="2" style="position: absolute; top: 100%;">
        </div>
        <div id="home-3" class="section" data-index="3" style="position: absolute; top: 200%;">
        </div>
        <div id="home-4" class="section" data-index="4" style="position: absolute; top: 300%;">
        </div>
        <div id="home-5" class="section" data-index="5" style="position: absolute; top: 400%;">
        </div>
        <div id="home-6" class="section" data-index="6" style="position: absolute; top: 500%;">
            <div id="footer">
                <div id="copyright">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

For the sample of page please refer  http://jainert.5gbfree.com/

you will find sample page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has zero to do with Bootstrap.

Read the docs of your scripts. It's not wise to use scripts w/o reading the docs.

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main').fullpage({
        scrollOverflow: false,
        easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
        autoScrolling: true,
        scrollingSpeed: 1200, /* change this value to control the speed*/
        slidesNavigation: true
});
```

Comment: hey Christina  thank you very much it's a silly mistake